# \Include working on mac, but not on windows

Tags: input, external-files, includegraphics, include, paths

I am working on a big LaTeX document (thesis), that's broken down into multiple .tex files, and I thus have only a thesismain.tex file to compile that uses \include.
On a MacBook, compilation goes fine.
Copying the whole folder on a Win10 machine, however, results in systematic "file not found" errors, although the files have also been copied.

I narrowed down the problem to the following :
My file paths, in the main file, all contain the letter "ô". When I hit delete in the tex file, on both mac and windows, strangely this letter "ô" does not disappear as a whole ; first the ^ does, and I have to hit the key a second time to get the o to disappear. If I then retype an "ô", then it gets deleted in one keystroke.
Upon replacing the ô "in two parts" by a ô "in one part", a file not found issue is resolved. However, this pseudo-solution

- is very impractical, since many, many files are imported at some point (note that the problem persists with \includegraphics, with the same solution).
- does not explain where the problem came from in the first place, nor prevents it from happening again.

Any clues on what's going on more precisely, and how I can fix that ? Thanks !

Comment: I guess the `ô` in your `.tex` files is a composed character i.e. it is created from an `o` and an accent, while your files use a pre-composed character. I would recommend avoiding all 'weird' characters in file names, including all accented characters, spaces etc. If the name of my document includes `ô`, I use `o` in the file name. This is especially important if you need cross-platform support. The best solution would be to rename the offending files, though you may also want to check the encoding of your `.tex` files. It should be `utf8`. Is it?

Comment: @cfr comment should be the solution. Avoid special characters in file names, whitespaces can cause trouble too. If you don't want to rename many files and folders manually, you could use a script which replaces such characters and white spaces.

Comment: Plus, keep in mind that Windows uses backslashes to separate folder on a path while Unix systems like Mac use regular slashes. I don't know your folder structure, but if it is nested this *might* (not have to) cause some problems too

Comment: Yes, @cfr's right. the "ô" character was represented in two different ways in the files/folders names and in the paths in my files. Anyways, I script-removed all the accents from the names & in the paths in which said names appeared, so I should be good now ! Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is a guess because I can't check it... but anyways.

Some accented chars, at least the most common, can be represented in two different ways: as a single codepoint or as a pair of them: the plain vowel (in this case) plus a combining accent.

In theory, every application should use the most compact way, but what to do is up to the editor, file system, etc. For example, Unix-like filesystems will use the file name as input, without any mangling, and will consider two files with a different encoded ô different. I have no idea what the Mac or Windows filesystems will do.

It seems you have a mix of the two representations in the files or the filesystem. If it's in the file, there should be a way of telling the editor to use a normalized encoding to avoid this.

See https://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html and https://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html for more info.

So yes, it's quite a mess... I usually try to avoid out-of-ASCII characters in files and directory names (and spaces, too... and colons `:` that are legal on most filesystems but not on some Windows ones... see https://superuser.com/a/748264 for the minimum common denominator).

On the other hand, do not worry about the / versus \ issue, LaTeX uses the first one for everything... even on Windows.

Comment: Good to know, that LaTeX always uses slashes. Never used it on Windows since I'm running GNU/Linux at home. Thus, my concern regarding that can be ignored @Kal8578

Comment: @lukeflo I'n on linux exclusively too, but I have colleagues using Windows/Mac... and fortunately, files are interchangeable. But I agree with you that if you can avoid using diacritics on file names, all the better.

Comment: Your edit to only use ASCII characters in file and directory names is the best guarantee to avoid such problems. If you are a native speaker of a language with many umlauts (like in my case German) or accented characters (like e.g. French), I've experienced that sometimes its just an unconcious habit to use these characters in file/directory names. To prevent problems like yours, @Kal8578, I for example wrote a script which I can run on my working dir ([script](https://gitlab.com/lukeflo/shell-readable-script); still unfinished but working). There are also Win programms for such cases or WSL.

Comment: Accepted answer, thanks ! You were right, I had a ô representation issue. I ended up getting rid of the accents, had to google a bit to find out how to do it for all files at once in a terminal but I should be good now. Also, thanks for having provided the set of safe characters, it made your answer all the more handy.

Comment: Since @Kal8578 asked me to write an answer, I'm rather surprised to find my comment turned into somebody else's.

Comment: @cfr sorry, I wrote that in the bus, not realizing you basically commented the same. Do you prefer I delete it or move it to community wiki?

Comment: @Rmano No, it's fine. Leave it as it is. Obviously, I didn't realise you were on the bus ;).

Comment: @cfr Fine! I think moving ir to CW is the right thing to do.

Comment: Sorry @cfr for accepting this answer while you commented before, i did not pay attention to who posted what, mb

Comment: @Kal8578 No worries. All sorted ;).